# VueJS v-model for object prop through nested components doesn't make update them as expected

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, nested, v-model

I'm developing an application form.
The components tree of it:

```
Application
    Form
        Fieldset
            Field
```

The Application component has configuration props for the Form component called `formSettings` so that it passes them so:

```
<application-form v-bind="formSettings"/>
```

Next, I need to synchronize FormData with the Fieldsets.

It's important that in my case all values to sync have an object type!

To achieve it, firstly, I've decided to make a deep clone of the fieldsets configuration prop to an inner attribute of the Form, called `form`, in the created hook, and additionally add a special attribute to each of them, called `value`, which stores all the values of the fieldset's fields:

```
created() {
  this.form.fieldsets = _.cloneDeepWith(this.fieldsets);
  this.form.fieldsets.forEach(fieldset => {
    fieldset.value = {};
    fieldset.fields.forEach(field => {
      fieldset.value[field.name] = field.value;
    })
  })
}
```

So that, the Form's template renders using this clone:

```
 <vue-fieldset v-for="(fieldset, i) in fieldsets"
               :key="`fieldset-${i}`"
               v-model="fieldset.value"
               v-bind="fieldset"/>
```

Next, I need to synchronize the Fieldsets value to their Fields. I tried an approach like in the Form component - to create an inner mutable attribute storing the clone of the components configuration props with their values. Using it doesn't update nested components as expected, and when I tried to change some field value in `form.fieldsets`, it doesn't change anything in child components so that I declined this approach. Another approach I use is to define a computed property in the Fieldset component:

```
computed: {
  collectedValue: {
    get() {
      return this.value
    },
    set(newValue) {
      this.$emit('update:value', newValue);
    }
  }
}
```

And then - use v-model on it:

```
<vue-input v-for="field in fieldset.fields"
           :key="field.name"
           v-model="collectedValue[field.name]"
           v-bind="field"/>
```

But it doesn't update the Fields components too.

What can I do to make nested v-model for objects work properly?

Comment: Have you tried using ```Vue.$set``` for setting properties?

Comment: @TimVN, no, thanks for an idea, I'll try, however it seems opposite to v-model pattern.

Comment: If you created a clone of your object, doesn't that make the components using it practically disconnected from the rest of the reactivity system?