# Is it bad to use v-model with object especially through several nested components in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, nested, v-model

I have a big problem using v-model with an object passed through 2 layers of nested components. I've described the problem here [VueJS v-model for object prop through nested components doesn't make update them as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903622/vuejs-v-model-for-object-prop-through-nested-components-doesnt-make-update-them?noredirect=1#comment98463412_55903622) . But now I'm wondering, maybe this approach is very bad and there are some reasons for it?

Answer (score 1):

One or two lvls of props is okay. If you need to waterfall your data deeper, use store. Divide your components into container components and stupid components. Containres have connection with store and they apss data down to their childrens. Stupid components only render data and emits changes.